# VBA Dynamic Regex Pattern Within "If"

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm working on a tool to pull multiple forms of reference numbers from text and I'm struggling to think of a smart way to iterate through different RegEx patterns. Example of what I'm after is something like (pseudocode for what I'm after in curly braces):

```
Dim regEx as New RegExp
Dim someinput as String

regEx.Pattern = "201[67]\W?\d{6}"

If regEx.Test(someinput) = True Then
   foo
Elseif {with regEx.pattern="AB\W?\d{10}"  regEx.Test(someinput)} Then
   bar
...
```

This is going to be several levels deep as we've got around a dozen possible formats to check through. All I can think of at the moment is defining a new regEx item for each, setting the patterns for each, then running through the If->ElseIfs one by one, but there must be a better way... I hope!

Thanks much

**Edit** Just to pre-empt, foo and bar will be different depending on the input, so I can't just make (for instance) an array of possible patterns and run through checking each one and then returning a final "True/False"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would do this in a loop:

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim someinput As String
Dim patterns
Dim i As Long
Dim match As Long
patterns = Array("201[67]\W?\d{6}", _
                 "AB\W?\d{10}")

match = -1
For i = LBound(patterns) To UBound(patterns)
    regEx.Pattern = patterns(i)
    If regEx.Test(someinput) Then
        match = i - LBound(patterns)  ' subtract the lower bound to force zero-base
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Select Case match
    Case 0: foo
    Case 1: bar
    Case Else: MsgBox "No match found"
End Select
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for your help :)